# flutter web build with tree shake icons

Tags: flutter, flutter-web, flutter-build

when I build flutter to web platform with command `--tree-shake-icons` I get this error.

```bash
This application cannot tree shake icons fonts. It has non-constant instances of IconData at the following locations:

file:///Users/xxx/Documents/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/icon_data.dart:22:9

file:///Users/xxx/Documents/hxgy/flutter/projectName/lib/utils/font_util/font_utils.dart:13:7
Target web_-release_bundle failed: Exception: Avoid non-constant invocations of IconData or try to build again with
--no-tree-shake-icons.
```

I need flutter to automatically compress the size of the font ICONS because they are too big，so I did not use `--no-tree-shake-icons` commander.

Comment: You need first run flutter build apk and then copy compressed otf cp -r ./build/app/intermediates/flutter/release/flutter_assets/ ./build/web/assets

Answer (score 3):

Flutter web doesn't support `--tree-shake-icons` yet. [This](https://medium.com/@GSYTech/how-to-optimize-flutter-web-and-how-flutter-web-work-in-html-renderer-b399ffd66718) could help.